# Using built in Calc function when recording a macro

Tags: function, built-in, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I am working through Excel for Engineers and trying to adapt it for LibreOffice Calc.  I have run into a problem.  I know this is easier to do without using macros but humor me. One of the exercises is to start recording a macro, type:

```
=RAND()
```

hit enter and stop recording.

When I run the macro nothing happens.  I try to use any other Calc built in function and the same thing happens.  Looking at the macro basic file and sure enough nothing is happening.

Can I use built in functions when recording a macro?  If so how?

Comment: Thanks!  I did not realize I needed to accept answers.  I believe I have accepted all of them where appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the LibreOffice macro recorder does not record adding built-in functions.  In fact, the recorder has many limitations and generally results in poor code (mostly using the dispatcher).

Instead, write API code based on documentation such as https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Function_Handling.

```vb
Sub CallSpreadsheetFunction
    funcAcc = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    oSheet = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
    oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")
    oCell.setValue(funcAcc.callFunction("RAND", Array()))
End Sub
```

A good place to start learning about LibreOffice macros is http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php.

Note that learning LibreOffice Basic will not help very much to learn about MS Office VBA.  The two languages and platforms are quite different.

Comment: Thank you.  I figured I could write the above code but was trying to replicate the exercises in the book for LibreOffice.  I am not trying to learn MS Office VBA.  I was adapting a book written for Excel.  But as I got further into the book the limitations of Calc got greater and greater.

Comment: "Limitations of Calc" - Compared with MS Office, LO is limited in many ways.  Compared with LO, MS Office is limited in many ways.  I think it's more accurate to say they are simply different, and problems come when trying to do what works with one suite in the other suite.